# Snap daemon is blocking boot after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, snap

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 in a *Dell G5-5587*, replacing a 100% working Ubuntu 18.04
I tried to install it for scratch and updating from 18.04, with the same problem.

When Ubuntu 20.04 starts, it is stuck in the `snap` initialization.

When I upgrade from 18.04, It is necessary to wait tens of minutes to pass all snapd steps: `Processing snap replacements`, `refreshing snap core18`, `installing snap gnome-3-34-1804`, etc...

After installing 20.04 from scratch or rebooting after upgrade from 18.04, it is stuck at boot time because `snapd` stuff, like `wait until snapd is fully seeded`.

As I say, Ubuntu 18.04.4 is working with no problems at all.

Please, advice. I don't know what to do next.

Note and clues:

- It works if I boot using "Advanced options for Ubuntu" -> "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-40-generic (rescue mode)" -> "resume".

Answer (score 3):

My problem was related to the GDM3. **It used the HDMI port even when no monitor was connected!!!!** And in the laptop display, it kept the booting Ubunto logging.

I installed lightdm and working again: `sudo apt install lightdm`

What is incredible is that issues related to GDM3 are constant. I waste the full day installing Ubuntu 20.04 in my son's laptops when the Ubuntu20.04 installation does not take more than 10 minutes.